# Prevented from "Save & Publish" without error or explanation

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have been tasked with converting a .mdb created in 2001 to an .accdb.  I've followed the MS instructions (File>Save & Publish>Save Database As>Access Database(*.accbd)>Save As) but literally nothing happens.  No error message, no on screen changes, no accdb created.  All suggestions, however basic, are welcome.

I'm using Office 2010 Pro Plus (14.0.7145.5000) 32 bit on Win 7 Sp1 32 bit if that makes any difference.

Comment: Due to a surprising lack of suggestions, I've "worked around" this issue by importing the .mdb into a blank .accdb.  I suspect things are going to go wrong with this at some point, but the queries and forms appear to be okay at the moment.  Please comment if you've had problems with this type of work around if you've been forced to use it.

Comment: Your solution should work just fine. If there is code involved, make sure you compile it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had similar problems in the past. In my cases it were always these three cases:

1. Incorrect VBA code. You can detect that with the "compile" function in the vba editor. Once there is no more compile error publishing works just fine.
2. Not enough disk space on your machine. I work in a enterprise environment with tiny memory space for each employee. Make sure you have enough free space. Rule of thumb: At least double the amount of your file you want to publish.
3. The file you want to publish is corrupted. In that case your Access database simpy doesn't work and you need to migrate the code and the forms to a new file.